# Pulling Row Data Into a Google Sheets Sidebar then replacing new entered data into original row selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

I am currently trying to modify a already written code to be able to pull in row data of certain columns into the Sidebar then after the user submits it updates the row that was selected.

I have been able to achieve pulling the exact Row columns into an array but have not been able to print them as values in the Sidebar nor update the selected row.
I have included all of my Sidebar code some of it may be unnecessary thank you all for your help.

SideBar Code.gs

```
//CREATE CUSTOM MENU
function onOpen() { 
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("User Input SideBar Menu")
    .addItem("Constr.Sidebar Form","showFormInSidebar")
    
    .addToUi();
}
 function onSelectionChange(e) {
  
  // const range = e.range;
  // var row = range.getActiveRowIndex();
  // var address = getRange(row,1).getValues();
  // var pco = getRange(row,26).getValues();
  // var psi = getRange(row,27).getValues();
  // var pdi = getRange(row,40).getValues();
  // var pdo = getRange(row,41).getValues();
  // var qa_inspection = getRange(row,63).getValues();
  // var qa_bonus = getRange(row,64).getValues();
  // var qai_super = getRange(row,65).getValues();
  // var qa_cert = getRange(row,66).getValues();
  // var qac_bonus = getRange(row,67).getValues();

  // document.getElementById('PCO').value = pco;
  // document.getElementById('PSI').value = psi;
  // document.getElementById('PDI').value = pdi;
  // document.getElementById('PDO').value = pdo;
  // document.getElementById('QAInspectDate').value = qa_inspection;
  // document.getElementById('QAOTBONUS').value = qa_bonus;
  // document.getElementById('QAISuper').value = qai_super;
  // document.getElementById('QACertDate').value = qa_cert;
  // document.getElementById('QACBonus').value = qac_bonus;

getValuesOfActiveRow();
document.getElementById('PCO').setValue(vs[0]);
}
//OPEN THE FORM IN SIDEBAR 
function showFormInSidebar(vs) {      
  var form = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate().setTitle( 'Details');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(form);
}

//PROCESS FORM
function processForm(formObject){ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Logger.log([formObject.first_name]);
  sheet.appendRow([
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
    formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.PCO,
                formObject.PSI,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.PDI,
                formObject.PDO,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                formObject.SPACE,
                
                formObject.QAInspectDate,
                formObject.QAOTBONUS,
                formObject.QAISuper,
                formObject.QACertDate,
                formObject.QACBonus
                
                //Add your new field names here
                ])
               ;
}

//INCLUDE HTML PARTS, EG. JAVASCRIPT, CSS, OTHER HTML FILES
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

// new code
function getValuesOfActiveRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('LC 2022V2');
  let vs = sh.getRange(sh.getActiveRange().getRow(),1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().map(r => [r[0], r[25], r[26], r[48], r[49], r[88], r[89], r[90], r[91], r[92]]);
  Logger.log(vs);
  return vs[0];
  
  
}

function saveValuesActiveRow(formObject) {
  //Logger.log(form);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('LC 2022V2');
  //sh.getRange(sh.getCurrentCell().getRow(), 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).setValues([[form.PCO,form.PSI,form.PDI,form.PDO,form.QAInspectDate,form.QAOTBONUS,form.QAISuper,form.QACertDate,form.QACBonus]])
sh.getRange(sh.getCurrentCell().getRow(),26).setValues(formObject.PCO);

}
```

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?> <!-- See JavaScript.html file -->
    <title>Contact Details</title>
  </head>
  
  <body class="bg-secondary text-light">
    <div class="container">
      <?!= include('Form'); ?> <!-- See Form.html file -->
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript.html

```
<script>
  // Prevent forms from submitting.
  function preventFormSubmit() {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);    
      
      
  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    //google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
    google.script.run.saveValuesActiveRow(formObject);
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  }
</script>

Form.htm

    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="PCO">PCO</label>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" class="form-control" id="PCO" name="PCO" placeholder="PCO" value="<?= row[0] ?>"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="PSI">PSI</label>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" class="form-control" id="PSI" name="PSI" placeholder="PSI" value="<?= row[1] ?>"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="PDI">PDI</label>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" class="form-control" id="PDI" name="PDI" placeholder="PDI" value="<?= row[2] ?>"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="PDO">PDO</label>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" class="form-control" id="PDO" name="PDO" placeholder="PDO" value="<?= row[3] ?>"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="QAInspectDate">QA Inspection Date</label>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="date" class="form-control" id="QAInspectDate" name="QAInspectDate" placeholder="QAInspectDate" value="<?= row[4] ?>"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="QAOTBONUS">QA OT BONUS</label>
        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="QAOTBONUS" name="QAOTBONUS" value="<?= row[5] ?>"/>
          <option value="" selected>Choose...</option>
          <option value="Fail1st">Fail 1st</option>
          <option value="Fail2nd">Fail 2nd</option>
          <option value="Fail3rd">Fail 3rd</option>
          <option value="Pass1st">Pass 1st</option>
          <option value="Pass2nd">Pass 2nd</option>
          <option value="Pass3rd">Pass 3rd</option>
        </select>
      </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="QAISuper">QAI Super</label>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" class="form-control" id="QAISuper" name="QAISuper" placeholder="QAISuper" value="<?= row[6] ?>"/>
      </div> 
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="QACertDate">QA Cert Date</label>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="date" class="form-control" id="QACertDate" name="QACertDate" placeholder="QACertDate" value="<?= row[7] ?>"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="QACBonus">QAC Bonus</label>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" class="form-control" id="QACBonus" name="QACBonus" placeholder="QACBonus" value="<?= row[8] ?>"/>
      </div> 
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Your script is too complex to decipher but if you are pulling Date objects from a Spreadsheet sheet they will not transfer to your Sidebar.  You need to format dates as string.  Try this first to make sure you are getting them to your sidebar.

Comment: I am pulling the selected row into an Array, i am having trouble finding how to pull the returned array into the Form in order to set the values of the sidebar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Description**

I think the difficulty in you scenario is your spreadsheet is so long (< 50 columns) you have difficulty editing certain columns.  So instead you want a dialog with the column values that you usually have to edit in a more concise form.

Here is an example of how to use HTMLTemplate to get the values of a selected row to a custom dialog, edit the values and return the new values to the spreadsheet.

I use the `mouseenter` event to determine if the user leaves the sidebar to pick a new row and returns to the sidebar and updates the values from the selecte row.

Here is my test sheet with sidebar before changing any values.  Change a value and hit the submit button to see what happens.

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen(e) {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let menu = ui.createMenu("Test");
  menu.addItem("Show SideBar","showSideBar");
  menu.addToUi();
}

function showSideBar() {
  try {
    let html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML_SideBar");
    html.data = getSelectedRow();
    html = html.evaluate();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

function getSelectedRow() {
  let cell = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell();
  let sheet = cell.getSheet();
  let row = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  row.forEach( (col,index) => { if( col instanceof Date ) row[index] = Utilities.formatDate(col,"GMT","MM/dd/yyyy") } );
  return JSON.stringify({ range: cell.getA1Notation(), row: row });
}

function setSelectedRow(row) {
  let cell = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell();
  let sheet = cell.getSheet();
  sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).setValues([row]);
}
```

**HTML_Sidebar.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mainContainer">
      <? var row = JSON.parse(data) ?>
      <label for="currentRange">Current Range:</label>
      <input id="currentRange" type="text" value="<?= row.range ?>">
      <label for="column1">Column 1:</label>
      <input id="column1" type="text" value="<?= row.row[0] ?>">
      <label for="column2">Column 2:</label>
      <input id="column2" type="text" value="<?= row.row[1] ?>">
      <label for="column3">Column 3:</label>
      <input id="column3" type="text" value="<?= row.row[2] ?>">
      <label for="column4">Column 4:</label>
      <input id="column4" type="text" value="<?= row.row[3] ?>">
      <label for="column5">Column 5:</label>
      <input id="column5" type="text" value="<?= row.row[4] ?>">
    </div>
    <input id="submitButton" type="button" value="Submit changes" onclick="submitOnClick()">
    <?!= include("JS_SideBar"); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS_SideBar.html

```
<script>
  function mainContainerMouseEnter() {
    try {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
        function (row) {
          row = JSON.parse(row);
          document.getElementById("currentRange").value = row.range;
          document.getElementById("column1").value = row.row[0];
          document.getElementById("column2").value = row.row[1];
          document.getElementById("column3").value = row.row[2];
          document.getElementById("column4").value = row.row[3];
          document.getElementById("column5").value = row.row[4];
        }
      ).withFailureHandler(
        function (err) {
          alert(err);
        }
      ).getSelectedRow();
    }
    catch(err) {
      alert("Error in mainContainerMouseEnter: "+err);
    }
  }

  function submitOnClick() {
    try {
      row = [];
      row[0] = document.getElementById("column1").value;
      row[1] = document.getElementById("column2").value;
      row[2] = document.getElementById("column3").value;
      row[3] = document.getElementById("column4").value;
      row[4] = document.getElementById("column5").value;
      google.script.run.withFailureHandler(
        function (err) {
          alert(err);
        }
      ).setSelectedRow(row);
    }
    catch(err) {
      alert("Error in submitOnClick: "+err);
    }
  }

  (function () {
    document.getElementById("mainContainer").addEventListener("mouseenter",mainContainerMouseEnter);
  })();
</script>
```

**References**

- [HTMLService Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)
- [SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getCurrentCell())
- [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities?hl=en#formatDate(Date,String,String))
- [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [mouseover event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp)